# Using n() with summarise_all

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

Works fine:

```
stats = c('mean', 'median', 'sd', 'max', 'min')
sumtable = iris %>% select(-Species) %>%  summarise_all(.funs = stats)
```

Doesn't work:

```
stats = c('mean', 'median', 'sd', 'max', 'min', 'n')
sumtable = iris %>% select(-Species) %>% summarise_all(.funs = stats)
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : `n()` does not take arguments
```

Please advise.

Comment: You can use `length` instead of `n`

Comment: Realize that for each function within your vector of named functions, `summarize_all` calls the function with the data as its first argument. So while `mean(x)` (or, more appropriately, `mean(c(1,2,5,22,...))`) makes sense, `n(...)` does not, as `n()` takes no arguments. You could always define `my_n <- function(...) n()` (to explicitly accept and ignore all arguments) and then `stats <- c(..., "my_n")` instead, but then you might as well use `length` as akrun suggested.

Comment: What would be the point of using `n()` with `summarize_all()`? `n()` returns the number of rows, which I asssume would be the same for all columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted this feature because I wanted to count non-missing observations. As Rohit pointed out, length would count all rows including missing obs. So what I did in the end was this:

```
not.na = function(x) {sum(!is.na(x))}
stats = c('mean', 'median', 'sd', 'max', 'min', 'not.na')
sum.acs = acs %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise_all(.funs = stats)
```